# Cyclic Group of order $8$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G=(a)$ be a cyclic group of order $8$ and let $H=(a^4)$ be its subgroup of order $2.$ Find the coset representation of $G$ by $H$.

Comment: How in the world can a "find this and that" question be proved by contradiction?! Would you go "suppose I cannot find, then..."?

Comment: Your proof showed that if for some $a\in G$ in a group of order 8, $|a^4|=2$, then $G$ is cyclic. Do you see how this does not help in finding a coset representation of $G$ by $H$?

Answer (score 4):

If $G$ is a cyclic group of order $8$ so it can be written as:
$$G=\langle a\rangle=\{e,a,a^2,a^3,a^4,a^5,a^6,a^7\}$$ You take $H\le G$ of order $2$ generated by $b=a^4$, so it is written:
$$H=\langle b\rangle=\{e,b\}$$ We have $[G:H]=4$ and since $G$ is cyclic so the subgroup $H\unlhd G$ and so we can speak about the quotient group $$G/H=\{gH\mid g\in H\}=\{H_1,H_2,H_3,H_4\}$$. Let's find this new group by its elements. We have then:
$$g=e\to gH=eH=H=H_1\\ g=a\to gH=aH=\{a,ab\}=\{a,a^5\}=H_2\\ g=a^2\to gH=a^2H=\{a^2,a^2b\}=\{a^2,a^6\}=H_3\\g=a^3\to gH=a^3H=\{a^3,a^3b\}=\{a^3,a^7\}=H_4\\g=a^4\to gH=a^4H=\{a^4,a^4b\}=\{a^4,a^8\}=\{a^4,a\}=H_1\\g=a^5\to gH=a^5H=\{a^5,a^5b\}=\{a^5,a^9\}=\{a^5,a\}=H_2\\g=a^6\to gH=a^6H=\{a^6,a^6b\}=\{a^6,a^{10}\}=\{a^6,a^2\}=H_3\\g=a^7\to gH=a^7H=\{a^7,a^7b\}=\{a^7,a^{11}\}=\{a^7,a^3\}=H_4\\$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: check that the cosets $\,H,a^3H,a^5H,a^6H\,$ are :

(1) All different ;

(2) $\,H\cup a^3H\cup a^5H\cup a^6H=G\,$

Why is the above enough? (hint: Lagrange's theorem)

Comment: Can you help me a little more. I just read how to do this. I know that H U a^3H U a^5 U a^6H = G. How would you show this though?

Comment: Well, to begin with: $\,H=\langle a^4\rangle=\{1,a^4\}\, $ ,so for example $$a^5H=a^3H\iff a^{-3}a^5=a^2\in H$$ and since $\,a^2\notin H\,$ we're done...as simple and short as that!. And to show (2), for example $$a^5H=\{a^5\cdot 1\,,\,a^5\,\cdot a^4\}=\{a^5\,,\,a^9=a\}$$...and etc.

Answer (score -1):

I am reading "Topics in Algebra 2nd Edition" by I. N. Herstein.
This problem is Problem 27 on p.82 in this book:

> Problem 27:
> Let $G=(a)$ be a cyclic group of order $8$ and let $H=(a^4)$ be its subgroup of order $2.$ Find the coset representation of $G$ by $H$.

The author wrote the definition of "the *coset representation* of $G$ by $H$" as follows on p.82:

> If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, let us call the mapping $\{t_g\mid g\in G\}$ defined in the discussion preceding Theorem 2.9.2 the *coset representation* of $G$ by $H$. This also realizes $G$ as a group of permutations, but not necessarily isomorphically, merely homomorphically (see Theorem 2.9.2).

The definition of $t_g$ is on p.72:

> Let $G$ be a group, $H$ a subgroup of $G$. Let $S$ be the set whose elements are the right cosets of $H$ in $G$. That is $S=\{Hg\mid g\in G\}$. $S$ need not be a group itself, in fact, it would be a group only if $H$ were a normal subgroup of $G$. However, we can make our group $G$ act on $S$ in the following natural way: for $g\in G$ let $t_g:S\to S$ be defined by $(Hx)t_g=Hxg$.

My solution of Problem 27 on p.82 is the following:

> $H=\{e,a^4\}$.
> $Ha=\{a,a^5\}$.
> $Ha^2=\{a^2,a^6\}$.
> $Ha^3=\{a^3,a^7\}$.
> $H\cup Ha \cup Ha^2 \cup Ha^3=G$.
> $H\cap Ha=\emptyset$.
> $H\cap Ha^2=\emptyset$.
> $H\cap Ha^3=\emptyset$.
> $Ha\cap Ha^2=\emptyset$.
> $Ha\cap Ha^3=\emptyset$.
> $Ha^2\cap Ha^3=\emptyset$.
> So, $S=\{H,Ha,Ha^2,Ha^3\}$.
> $t:G\ni g\mapsto t_g\in A(S)$ is a homomorphism.
> If $t_g=\operatorname{id}$, then $Hx=Hxg$ for all $x\in G$.
> So, $H=He=Heg=Hg$.
> So, $g\in H$.
> Conversely, if $g\in H$, then $Hxg=Hgx=Hx$ for all $x\in G$.
> So, $t_g=\operatorname{id}$.
> So, $\operatorname{Ker} t = H$.
> So, the coset representation of $G$ by $H$ is the following:
> $$t_e=t_{a^4}=\begin{pmatrix}H&Ha&Ha^2&Ha^3\\H&Ha&Ha^2&Ha^3\end{pmatrix}.$$
> $$t_a=t_{a^5}=\begin{pmatrix}H&Ha&Ha^2&Ha^3\\Ha&Ha^2&Ha^3&H\end{pmatrix}.$$
> $$t_{a^2}=t_{a^6}=\begin{pmatrix}H&Ha&Ha^2&Ha^3\\Ha^2&Ha^3&H&Ha\end{pmatrix}.$$
> $$t_{a^3}=t_{a^7}=\begin{pmatrix}H&Ha&Ha^2&Ha^3\\Ha^3&H&Ha&Ha^2\end{pmatrix}.$$

Is my solution ok?